# OneDriveSetup.exe causes high CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, onedrive, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1809

On my Toshiba Encore 8 Tablet I noticed that the CPU usage is very high. In Taskmgr / ProcessExplorer, I can see that `OneDriveSetup.exe` is hogging 1 CPU cores heavily for hours.

[image]

How an I solve this hang and finish the OneDrive Update?

Comment: See this [GitHub: Onedrive-Uninstaller](https://github.com/TERRAOperative/OneDrive-Uninstaller).

Comment: @Biswa I don't want to uninstall OneDrive, I wanted to fix the hang while updating.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a known issue since End of June 2017 when users have non English/ASCII values in their username and therefore their profile paths (`C:\Users\André`, `C:\Users\András` or Cyrillic user name). OneDriveSetup.exe hangs with a single processor thread hogging one logical processor of the computer because it keeps retrying file operations that are failing because of the non-English/ASCII characters in the user profile paths. Use [these steps to fix it](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fanswers.microsoft.com%2Fde-de%2Fwindows%2Fforum%2Fwindows_10-performance%2Fonedrivesetupexe-32bit-lastet-cpu-dauerhaft-mit-ca%2Fae516fe5-7b88-4e87-bf37-fbc94d1a7664&edit-text=):

1. Kill the `OneDriveSetup.exe` in Task Manager/Process Explorer; This step is optional, `OneDriveSetup.exe` will most likely recover from the hang and continue after step 2 even if you don't kill it (step 1) and run it again (step 3).
2. Go to the `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\setup\logs` folder and find the following two files
   `UserTelemetryCache.otc`
   `UserTelemetryCache.otc.session`
   <sup>(if you can't see them, [make sure all hidden & system files are visible](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files))</sup>
3. Now delete those 2 files and go to `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\Update` and run the `OneDriveSetup.exe` again.

Now the installer no longer hangs in a loop, finishes fine and the CPU usage is gone.

Comment: I wonder how many people have this problem. All WIndows 10 users? Or some language only? I noticed this happening for more then a week. Maybe it would be fixed in next Microsoft patch tuesday... What do you think? Obviously majority of people don't even notice it or don't even try to fix it like this.

Comment: @Vitas I had this issue since this week and found topics in Microsoft forums, too. So it effects users, but most users don't notice it.

Comment: Some people point to the fact that their username has accents in that. That would also explain how it slipped through the QA department. Anyway, I have the very same problem with an accent in my username `\Users\András`.

Comment: @atoth good catch. My path is C:\Users\André

Comment: and my USERPROFILE is in Cyrillic

Comment: @62mkv thanks now we see the issue. Non english/ASCII values in username seam to cause the hang while OneDrive update

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life. This issue was annoying me for a month.

Comment: Thank you. My laptop was running so hot because the CPU never slowed down. I have a username /users/Lars Meldgård

Comment: @LarsMeldgård nice to hear that  this fixes your issue, too.

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2018 - the problem still exists.

Comment: @lx07 ok, it never came back after I applied the fix, but nice to hear it still fixes the issue for other users.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - it helped me, yes and the problem hasn't reoccured again.  I proposed an edit to replace "C:\Users\your username\AppData\Local\" with "%localappdata%\" to make it easier to copy/paste but it was rejected by for some reason.  In any case it still works and is (at least in my case) applicable.

Comment: @lx07 ok, I made the edit.